# How to understand the wait and notify method in Java Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, notify

I'm very confusing about these two descriptions:

1. "The wait method blocks the calling thread and gives up the monitor lock"
2. "The notify method unblocks one waiting thread but does not give up the monitor lock"

Here is my questions:

1. I know each object in Java has a lock, but what is the "monitor lock" means? is it the same as the oject's lock?
2. Why notify method needs to give up the monitor lock?
3. If I try to make a object  waiting with the following code:

   ```
   class simpleTask extends Thread
   {
       int waitingTime;

       public simpleTask(int waitingTime)
       {
           this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
       }

       public void run()
       {
           synchronized(this) // this is a reference of current object
           {
           try {
               this.wait(waitingTime);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Like the first description above, is that means the the current object is blocked by synchronized keyword, and then wait method releases the lock?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know each object in Java has a lock, but what is the "monitor lock" means? is it the same as the object's lock?

Yes, they are the same thing.  They are also occasionally called the object's "mutex" and the object's "primitive lock".  (But when someone talks about `Lock`, they are talking about [this Java interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) ... which is a *different* locking mechanism.)

> Why notify method needs to give up the monitor lock?

The `notify` method *doesn't* give up the lock.  It is your code's responsibility to give up the lock (i.e. leave the synchronized block or return from the synchronized method) after the `notify` call returns.

Why is that necessary?  Because any other thread that is currently waiting on that lock (in a `wait(...)` call) has to reacquire that lock before the `wait` call can complete.

Why did they design `notify` / `wait` like this?  So that they can be used to implement condition variables.

> Like the first description above, is that means the the current object is blocked by synchronized keyword, and then wait method releases the lock?

That is correct.  When a thread calls `someObject.wait()` its lock on `someObject` is released ... and then reacquired (by the same thread) before the `wait()` call returns.  Of course, in the meantime the lock `someObject` *may* have been acquired and released multiple times by *other* threads.  The point is that when `wait` returns, the thread that called `wait` will have the lock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in your explain:"When you call someObject.wait() the thread's lock on someObject is released ... and then reacquired before the wait() call returns", who will reacquire the lock before the wait() call returns? Thanks again!

Comment: @Miles Zhang: The same thread will reacquire it, provided it's available (i.e. some other thread did not already acquire it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the monitor lock is the same as the object's lock. If you do `synchronized (object)`, that's the lock.
2. In your example, the current object will give up the lock while waiting, the `wait()` call gives up the lock. In another thread, `notify()` is called to wake the object up, and when the  `wait()` call returns it will hold the lock again.

Answer (score 0):

[A monitor is a type of synchronization construct.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29)

The reason that waiting gives up the lock is so that other threads can acquire the lock, such as other threads that might want to wait.  Also: It's usual for the thread that's awakening other threads to lock before releasing any threads, to prevent a race condition.

For more about this, you should study condition variables (i.e. condvars).

Comment: Thanks! I will get some knowledge about condition variables.